# 8 Bit Surfaces in SDL 2

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, color-depth

Originally in SDL, the following code could be used to setup a surface:

```
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 8, 0);
```

Now, in SDL2 the following code must be used:

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, 0);
SDL_Surface *surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
```

My problem is that SDL_CreateWindow offers no way to set the bbp of the window or surface. It seems to default to 32 bit. I've tried using `SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat` but `surface->format->BitsPerPixel` stays at 32.

How can I create a 8 bit surface in SDL 2? I realize I will need a color palette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SDL_CreateRGBSurface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface) where you can specify number of bits.

Example:

```
SDL_Window *sdlWindow;
SDL_Renderer *sdlRenderer;
SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(0, 0, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP, &sdlWindow, &sdlRenderer);

SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 640, 480, 32,
                                    0x00FF0000,
                                    0x0000FF00,
                                    0x000000FF,
                                    0xFF000000);
SDL_Texture *sdlTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(sdlRenderer,
                                        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
                                        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
                                        640, 480);

SDL_UpdateTexture(sdlTexture, NULL, screen->pixels, screen->pitch);
SDL_RenderClear(sdlRenderer);
SDL_RenderCopy(sdlRenderer, sdlTexture, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I the set that as `window`'s surface?

Comment: @Tyler0425 Added an example.

Comment: I'll have to use a texture and renderer?

Comment: @Tyler0425 I'm not sure if you can do without, have a look at [MigrationGuide](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been able to get everything working, except when I use this with an 8bit surface, the surface's color palette isn't touched in the rendering process, so all the colors are messed up.

Comment: @Tyler0425 you will need to post your code showing the problem